# Can llvm aliases be used for inter-module or only intra-module?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

LLVM defines [aliases for global values](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#aliases):

```
@<Name> = [Linkage] [PreemptionSpecifier] [Visibility] [DLLStorageClass] [ThreadLocal] [(unnamed_addr|local_unnamed_addr)] alias <AliaseeTy>, <AliaseeTy>* @<Aliasee>
```

What are valid `<Aliasee>` values?

1. Only names that occur somewhere else in the current modules or
2. also names that occur in other modules that are linked in later?

I thought inter-module aliases were permitted but I cannot get it to work. I keep getting errors of this type:

```
<string>:5:39: error: use of undefined value '@my_name'
@"MyAlias" = external alias i32, i32* @my_name
                                      ^
```

Note: `@my_name` is not defined in the current module. It is defined in another module.

Answer (score 0):

Anything represented in LLVM IR needs to be declared. Your `my_name` should be declared as well. Note, however, that aliases are created to the existing definition. See the section "Restrictions" in the manual:

Since aliases are only a second name, some restrictions apply, of which some can only be checked when producing an object file:

- The expression defining the aliasee must be computable at assembly time. Since it is just a name, no relocations can be used.
- No alias in the expression can be weak as the possibility of the intermediate alias being overridden cannot be represented in an object file.
- No global value in the expression can be a declaration, since that would require a relocation, which is not possible.